# MySQL Average of two selects?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, union, average

I'm trying to take the average time of two selects and return them
to see what percentage of time has gone by since the last order. It
is part of an early alert system if you're wondering why.

Select 1 takes 5 of the (almost) most current datetimes, records 2-6
for example to get the average of some of the last ordered products.

Select 2 (I don't think its working) takes the average of the current
order and NOW() to see how much time has gone by since the last order.

The return should be the average time between those recent orders and
the last order placed. I evidently have some bugs in my code, and can
not get it to work...

I dunno, I'm hoping some obvious stuff sticks out, like how I botched the
`UNION()` or muddled the second `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`

```
SELECT (spread + recent) / 2 AS lapse FROM 

    (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(created_at), MAX(created_at) ) 
               /
               (COUNT(DISTINCT(created_at)) -1) 

          FROM (  SELECT created_at
            FROM dbname.sales_flat_order_status_history 
            ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 1
             ) 

          AS created_at) AS spread,

UNION

    (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(created_at), NOW() ) 
               /
               (COUNT(DISTINCT(created_at)) -1) 

          FROM (  SELECT created_at
            FROM dbname.sales_flat_order_status_history 
            ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
             ) 

          AS created_at) AS recent;

ORDER BY lapse LIMIT 1;
```